# output logs into /var/log/syslog

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

Our legacy system was outputting to `/var/log/syslog` with `posix` module without any tuning. But this `posix` package is no longer available in Node.js v10, we had to adopt other logging module.

We are now trying to use `winston` module instead of it, and our setting is like below.

```
this.logger = winston.createLogger({
  levels: winston.config.syslog.levels,
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: '/var/log/syslog'
    })
  ]
});
```

But we can't get any logs in `/var/log/syslog`, maybe it is due to the permission problem.
Does anyone have the best solution for this?
What we would like to do is to enable to output logs into `/var/log/syslog` with ease settings.

I think the best way is to change destination file, if you don't have any better way, just tell 'change the destination file' to me.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: there were  no messages I got, just no logs in `/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 1):

You most probably have indeed a permission problem considering /var/log/syslog is managed by system utilities.

Anyway the fastest solution is to use the npm package [winston-syslog](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-syslog), it is pretty easy to configure if you look at the documentation

```
const winston = require('winston');

//
// Requiring `winston-syslog` will expose
// `winston.transports.Syslog`
//
require('winston-syslog').Syslog;

winston.add(new winston.transports.Syslog(options));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I couldn't get any logs in `/var/log/syslog` . What should I pass `options` to `winston-syslog` ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can output log to console and redirect stdout and stderr streams to files